# what are the different communication methods available?

Tags: ros, communication, wifi, bluetooth

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Im not talking about services etc. I mean what communication methods could be used between a laptop running ROS and a robot running ROS?

i mean the actual data transfer medium..wifi? Zigbee? bluetooth? ethernet? UWB?

has anyone played around with different ways to do communication?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/213519/what-are-the-different-communication-methods-available?/) by [hommsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23145/hommsy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 31 on 2015-07-12

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is everything possible aslong you can tunnel TCP-Communication. For communication within in the robot(one Roscore) I prefer Ethernet, to connect the services. For commication between a Command&Controll and the Robot I Use Wifi (and an ligtwith UDP protokol), if longdistance communication is neccery, I would use Zigbee and Rosserial and Bluetooh is nice way to connect a Remotecontroll with Real-Visual feedback.

Greet

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2015-07-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [hommsy](https://answers.ros.org/users/23145/hommsy/) on 2015-07-12**:
thank you  for your input. Thats helpful. Do you know of any scientific paper that says so? it seems there are no papers targeting the communication between the "Command&Control" and the robot..any ideas?

**Comment by [Ajan](https://answers.ros.org/users/25114/ajan/) on 2015-11-23**:
If I want to use Bluetooth as the underlying medium of communication between different ROS nodes which controls various parts of the robot, how would I implement it.  I understand that ROS works on TCP. So I should enable Bluetooth profile which is capable of supporting TCP. PPP? any suggestions?

**Comment by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) on 2015-11-24**:
I you can Chose, you can configure Bluetooth PAN, and you have an TCP/Connection